# Solving Equation Using Algebraic Method

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to solve these equations using an algebraic method?
I need to show my working, don't you do something in reverse, like 7 multiplies by something. I haven't done it in class.

$$\dfrac{5(3y-4)}{2y}=7$$

Comment: $\dfrac{5(3y-4)}{2y}=7 \implies$

$5(3y-4)=14y$, bring all the like factors together. And you get the value of $y$.

Comment: @Inceptio please can you edit it for me, i'm not sure how

Comment: HonkyHanka: Enclose `\frac{5(3y-4)}{2y}=7` in dollar signs. When you have a little time, and for reference, see this nice [mathjax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). You can start simply, formatting equations like $x^2 + y^2 = 1$, e.g.: `$x^2 + y^2 = 1$`

Comment: Ok thanks but any answers lol?

Answer (score 3):

Multiply each side of the equation by $2y$ to get:

$$\dfrac{5(3y-4)}{2y}=7 \iff 5(3y - 4) = 7\cdot 2y = 14 y$$

Now, distribute, and then gather "like terms", and simplify:

$$
\begin{align} 5(3y - 4)  = 14 y & \iff 15y - 20 = 14y \\ \\
& \iff 15y - 14y = 20 \\ \\
& \iff y = 20.
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{equation*}
\frac{5(3y-4)}{2y}=7.\tag{0}
\end{equation*}
$$

> like 7 multiplies by something

- The given equation is only defined when the denominator of the left-hand side is different from $0$. So assume that $y\ne 0$. Then  you can multiply both sides of equation $(0)$ by $2y$ to obtain an *equivalent* one, i.e. the new equation has the same solution as the original.  $$
  \begin{eqnarray*}
  \frac{5(3y-4)}{2y}\times 2y &=&7\times 2y \tag{1$\mathrm{a}$} \\
  \Leftrightarrow5(3y-4) &=&14y \tag{1$\mathrm{b}$} \\
  \Leftrightarrow15y-20 &=&14y,\qquad\text{after expanding the LHS}.\tag{1$\mathrm{c}$}
  \end{eqnarray*}$$
- You can subtract $14y$ from both sides. The new equation is *equivalent* to the previous  one:
  $$
  \begin{eqnarray*}
  15y-20-14y &=&14y-14y \tag{2$\mathrm{a}$}\\
  \Leftrightarrow y-20 &=&0.\tag{2$\mathrm{b}$}
  \end{eqnarray*}
  $$
- You can add $20$ to both sides. The new equation is *equivalent* to the previous  one:
  $$
  \begin{eqnarray*}
  y-20+20 &=&0+20 \tag{3$\mathrm{a}$}\\
  \Leftrightarrow y &=&20.\tag{3$\mathrm{b}$}
  \end{eqnarray*}
  $$
- Since the solution $y=20\neq 0$, the multiplication in 1 is valid.

**Comment**. In general to get an *equivalent* equation one can:

- *multiply* or *divide* both sides of a given equation by the same value, provided that it is different from $0$.
- *add* or *subtract* the same value to and from both sides.
- *Simplify* either side according to the algebraic rules as in $(1\mathrm{b})$ to $(1\mathrm{c})$.

Answer (score 0):

We are given:

$\dfrac{5(3y-4)}{2y}=7$

We must next eliminate the $2y$ from the denominator. We can do this by multiplying $2y$ by the $7$ on the other side of the equation. What we have now is a straightforward solve for y question.

$\implies$ $5(3y-4)=7(2y)$

$\implies$ $15y-20=14y$

We must now isolate y.

$\implies$ $15y-20=14y\implies15y-14y=20\implies y=20$

We can now check our solution to see if we are correct by plugging the value of y (which is 20) back into the initial equation.

$\dfrac{5(3(20)-4)}{2(20)}=7$

$\dfrac{5(60-4)}{40}=7$

$\dfrac{280}{40}=7$

We find that 7 is indeed equal to 7 which proves our answer is correct.
$7=7$